# How to pass size_t template arguments in function-signature style?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define a class `A` which expects a type `T` and an arbitrary number of size_t `N_i...` as its template arguments:

```
template< typename T, size_t... N_i>
class A
{
  // ...
};
```

According to `A`'s defintion above, I have to pass the template arguments to `A` in the form `A<float,1,2,3> a` (for the example case of `T=float` and `N_i...=1,2,3`), however,
for a better reading, I would prefer a (function-signature-style) syntax, i.e., `A<float, (1,2,3)> a` where the size_t values are passed in parentheses. Does anyone know how this can be implemented?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can't have that exact syntax with C++ templates. You have to make a compromise.

Comment: You can still do macro `#define NS(...) __VA_ARGS__` and then `A<float, NS(1,2,3)> a;`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have exactly that syntax in C++ (the parenthesized list would be an expression containing comma operators, would be equal to the last value).

**Edit** The following first draft won't work:  Roughly speaking, a non-type parameter must be an integral/enum type, a reference, or some sort of pointer.  See [this list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) for the actual exhaustive list.

If you are prepared to accept curly braces instead:

```
template< typename T, std::initializer_list<size_t> N_i>
class A
{
  // ...
};

A<float, {1,2,3}> a;
```

**Edit**
You can force it to work by changing it to:

```
template< typename T, const std::initializer_list<size_t> *N_i>
class A
{
  // ...
};

const std::initializer_list<size_t> a_arg{1,2,3}
A<float, &a_arg> a;
```

But this breaks "readability" horribly.

There are other complex solutions involving a magic type which has a suitable comma operator, but a) making that acceptable as a template argument is hard; b) the readability will be worse than what you started with.

Comment: No, that's not a valid template non-type parameter type.

Comment: @T.C.:  Fixed(ish)